# launching a modal view controller to work around the orientation "lock" of tab bar and nav VCs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I have an iPhone app with a root view controller (VC) of UITabBarController (set to portrait orientation) with several tabs, one of which is a simple UIViewController.  In that UIViewController is a single button - "Play Video", which, when clicked opens a modal view of the video (and automatically starts playing the video).  The video view is a UIWebView in a UIViewController.  I've been trying to get the Web View's VC to change orientation to landscape but have not had any luck.

I've looked around and understand that if you have a Tab Bar or a Nav controller, all children VCs will be the same orientation as the parent - makes sense.  This is why I made the web view's VC modal, hoping this is a way around the orientation issue.

My question is: is this accurate - that using modal will not require the web view VC to be portrait and can respond to the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method (even though I have not yet been able to get it to work)?

BTW, using iOS 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in ios6 and above, the way rotation works is different. So what you have to do is the following

1. In your .plist support all 4 orientations.
2. Subclass the UITabBarController (for e.g: CustomTabBarController)
3. In the CustomTabBarController put the following lines of code

   ```
   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }


   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
   }
   ```
4. In your app delegate or where ever you are initializing UITabBarController, replace those instances with CustomTabBarController instances.
5. In your modal controller put the lines

   ```
   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
   }

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
       return NO;

   }
   ```

And it should all work.

Apparently the trick, I found is that, UITabBarController will not listen to your instructions. It will support all the orientations you mention in the .plist.

There fore you have to subclass it.

I tried doing all of the above and it works fine. Do let me know and I can send you the code if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just have portrait set in the summary screen, then in the app delegate, implement this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

In the tab bar controller (and no other rotation code):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

And finally, in the modal view controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```