# How to prevent autorotation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, autorotate

In my iphone app I wish to rotate only one view when device rotated.How can I do this.
I have selected Supported interface orientation as Portrait,rotate right and rotate left

How can I rotate only one view.
Actually I want to rotate the MPMoviePlayer when it became full screen.

Answer (score 1):

for your view controller set return value NO to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{

return NO;
}
```

you can also remove it from Plist. UISupportedInterfaceOrientations

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller needs to respond to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

return YES to allow, and NO to disallow autorotation.

Better explanation is here:
[AutoRotate ONLY MpMoviePlayerControler iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773179/autorotate-only-mpmovieplayercontroler-ios-6?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller, if don't want rotate add this

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return NO;
}
```

In your view controller, if want rotate add this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```